# How can I concatenate compound language objects in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to build up expressions in R by concatenating smaller expressions. For example in S+ I can do this:

```
> x = substitute({a;b;c})
> y = substitute({d;e;f})
> c(x,y)
{
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
}
```

but if I try it in R, I get this:

```
> c(x,y)
[[1]]
{
    a
    b
    c
}

[[2]]
{
    d
    e
    f
}
```

Should I be doing this another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comments attached to @baptiste's answer make the point that `x` and `y` are not objects of type `"expression"` (one of the nine basic vector types used by R). Thus, they can't by combined by using `c()`, as they could if they were in fact `expression` vectors.

If you really do want to combine objects of class `"{"` (which are called "compound language objects" in [this section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expression-objects) of the R Language Definition) you could do something like this:

```
x <- substitute({a;b;c})
y <- substitute({d;e;f})
class(x)
# [1] "{"

as.call(c(as.symbol("{"), c(as.list(x)[-1], as.list(y)[-1])))
{
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
}
```

Then, if you were going to be doing this frequently, you could create a function that combines an arbitrary set of objects of class `"{"`:

```
myC <- function(...) {
    ll <- list(...)
    ll <- lapply(ll, function(X) as.list(X)[-1])
    ll <- do.call("c", ll)
    as.call(c(as.symbol("{"), ll))
}

# Try it out
myC(x, y, y, y, x)
```

Comment: This seems like a very elegant solution. In the `as.call(c(as.symbol("{"), c(as.list(x)[-1], as.list(y)[-1])))`, is the second `c(` necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the example you gave in your question for the time being,

```
x = expression(a,b,c)
y = expression(d,e,f)
c(x,y)
```

Now, what sort of objects are you trying to concatenate?

Comment: hmmm.  Beyond my knowledge:  is an object of type "expression" the same as an object of type "language" ?

Comment: There's something in R/S called an "expression" which is an unevaluated program. It's basically a list (as in Lisp). I want to take two short ones and combine them into one long one. In Lisp it would be called `(conc x y)`. I can't find the right function to do it in R.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `?"language-class"` seems to indicate that `{a;b;c}` is a bit like a `call`, except that it has no proper `function`. Its elements can be accessed with `sapply(seq.int(length(x)-1), languageEl, object=x)`. So, in my feeble understanding, `expression` extends `call`, which extends `language`. Thus, `languageEl(expression(a,b,c), 2)` also works.

Comment: If you want to ask a question, then do so in a comment. This in no way answers the question asked.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey -- baptiste's answer (+1) is actually the correct one.  Your difficulties are arising from the fact `substitute({a; b; c})`, like `quote({a; b; c})` does not return an object of class `expression`. Instead, they both return what the R Language Definition manual http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expression-objects calls "compound language objects", of class `"{"`. To get an object of class expression, you need to either parse some text string, or call `expression(a, b, c)`, as baptiste did. The resulting object will behave just as you expected it to.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien `substitute` is different from `expression`. The latter simply creates an expression. The former substitutes variables into an expression. For example, `substitute(expression(a*b+3-c), list(a=42,c=666))`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the question was "How can I concatenate expressions in R?" and I answered that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `substitute(expression(a*b+3-c), list(a=42,c=666))` returns a `call`. You need to `eval()` it to obtain an `expression`, as detailed in `?substitute`. And, of course, `eval(x)` returns an error for the original example since `x` isn't even a `call` but raw `language`.

Comment: Question looks more like how to concatenate the objects that substitute returns. You didn't answer that. Anyway, the explanations in the comments should be in your answer. As it stands this answer is sorely lacking.

Comment: Please update the body of this post so that it contains the solution from the comments.  Thanks.

Comment: My impression from the beginning was that the *question* would need an update, at least some clarification of the real goal; this point has not come across for some reason, and the OP has not given me motivation to update my answer. As far as I know people are free to contribute their own answer to the original question if they interpret it differently ("Should I be doing this another way?"). @JoshO'Brien has now kindly provided an answer to accommodate everyone's wishes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to grab the elements of `x` and `y`. It will always be the case that `x[1]` is "{}" , so you could do:

```
 x[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+length(y)-1)] <- y[2:(length(y))]
```

Though I imagine there's a cleaner way.