# How do I collapse/merge expression objects in R?

Tags: r

Imagine I generate an R `expression` object by concatenation:

```
x = c(expression({
      a + b
      b + c
      }), 
      expression({
      a + 1
      b + 1
      }))
```

This results in a length-2 expression object:

```
> x
expression({
    a + b
    b + c
}, {
    a + 1
    b + 1
})
```

How can I transform/collapse this into a single expression? That is, I'm looking for an operation I can perform on `x` to get the equivalent of having done this:

```
expression({
    a + b
    b + c
    a + 1
    b + 1
})
```

Comment: `deparse`, combine the middles, re`parse`? This is almost there: `c_exp = function(x1, x2) parse(text = c(head(deparse(x1), -1), tail(deparse(x2), -1)))`

Comment: @nongkrong `as.expression(list(x[[1]][[2]], x[[2]][[2]]))` looks promising, but I need a general solution that doesn't care how many lines are in the individual expressions, or how many expressions are involved.  Though I can probably build on your approach.

Comment: @cboettig - your are aware that in your update you would only receive the result of `b + 1` when you evaluate the expression?

Comment: @RichardScriven of course.  Here I'm just trying to create the unevaluated expression. (minimal example here, happy to share the context if you're interested)

Comment: Related: [How can I concatenate compound language objects in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744729/how-can-i-concatenate-compound-language-objects-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = c(expression({
  a + b
  b + c
  }), 
  expression({
  a + 1
  b + 1
  }))

collapsit = function(x) {
    if(!all(sapply(x, class) == "{"))
        stop("I can't collapse non-bracket expressions for you, dawg")

    stuff = unlist(lapply(x[-1], function(y) as.list(y[-1])))
    x[[1]][length(x[[1]])+1:length(stuff)] = stuff
    x[1]
}

res = collapsit(x)
## expression({
##     a + b
##     b + c
##     a + 1
##     b + 1
## })
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, each expression should start with `{`

```
as.expression(sapply(x, function(y) as.list(y[-1])))
# expression(a + b, b + c, a + 1, b + 1)
```

Comment: Nice!  I had just tried that with `lapply` instead of `sapply` and then gave up.  @hadley mentions getting down to just the `call` with `y[-1]` in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html but I couldn't collapse the resulting lists.  nice work

Comment: but this gives an expression of length 4 whereas the desired output was to collapse into one expression, right? also if you try this with my `x` example, it messes up the last expression and splits the `x + y` into `x` and `y` and gives a length of 6

Comment: @rawr yea, as it says, the subexpressions should start with `{`, you need to fix the last expression up

Comment: @nongkrong uh ok but sometimes it won't. and you answer still isn't the desired output

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require each expression to be in brackets as in the `x + y` expression:

```
x = c(expression({
  a + b
  b + c
  }), 
 expression({
  a + 1
  b + 1
  }),
 expression(x + y))

# expression({
#   a + b
#   b + c
# }, {
#   a + 1
#   b + 1
# }, x + y)

s <- strsplit(paste0(as.character(x), collapse = ''), '[\n{}]')[[1]]
x <- paste0(Filter(nzchar, gsub('^\\s+|\\s+$','', s)), collapse = '\n')
parse(text = sprintf('{\n%s\n}', x))

# expression({
#   a + b
#   b + c
#   a + 1
#   b + 1
#   x + y
# })
```

Comment: That is one heck of a solution!  It fits the bill for me, though it seems like one should be able to do this without resorting to direct string manipulation (which makes me nervous); e.g. with the `call` objects http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html but I cannot quite see how.

Answer (score 2):

This produces the desired results, and could probably be scaled up to take more inputs with `reduce` or somesuch. That said, I'm not sure how *good* of a solution this is as I don't often make use of expressions.

```
c_exp = function(x1, x2) {
    parse(text = c("{",
                   tail(head(deparse(x1), -1), -1),
                   head(tail(deparse(x2), -1), -1),
                   "}"))
}

x1 = expression({a+b})
x2 = expression({a + 1})
c_exp(x1, x2)
# expression({
#     a + b
#     a + 1
# })
```